# Update all phone numbers to 10 characters

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have a table which has phone numbers filled. There are many records of phones numbers. Some are of 10 characters, while some are less than 10 and some are greater than 10. Now I want to select the records then update all the records to 10 characters. If phone number is of less than 10 characters, add leading 0 to make it 10. If greater than 10, then remove last digits to make 10.

Comment: You can use case in sql query with length function. http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-length-function.php &  http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/case-operator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET MOBILE = 
            CASE WHEN LENGTH(MOBILE) <= 10 THEN LPAD(MOBILE, 10, '0')
                 WHEN LENGTH(MOBILE) > 10 THEN SUBSTRING(MOBILE, 1, 10) 
            END
```

Here I had used [**SUBSTRING**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php) and [**LENGTH**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-length-function.php) function of MySQL

Using both of above function you can conditionally update your all records.

Try above query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` to get a 10 characters string, and `str_pad` to add '0' to the end or the beginning of your string.

```
<?php
$numbers = ['9876543210',
        '987654321000',
        '6543210',
        '876543210',
        '9876543210111',
        '98765432101'];
foreach($numbers as &$number){
    $number = substr(str_pad($number,10,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT),0,10);
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export data to Excel(CSV) and Update all data by manually
2. If you have lot of record use PHP Script (better catch exeptions, and lot of choices how edit different type of formats)
3. Create some Update query (use `lenght, lpad, substring` etc.)

But, why do you need to do such extreme edit with the data? Do you need to fill all phone numbers that have less than 10 characters and add 0 value? (Will not you miss some important data if you cut them off?) In my point of view, it is better to remove whitespaces and special characters. Any international preferences that you can store in another table or in the same table but in another column. In PHP scripts you can find here at StackOverflow  a lot of examples of how to make adjustments and conversions of phone numbers.